# Login and password using list

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I want to put entry data to the list of dictionaries to create a simple data base

I couldn't find adequate information about working with dictionaries in array.

```
workerspass = [{"someKey_2":"a"}, {"someKey_3":"b"}, {"somekey_1":"a"}]
def publish():

     global workerspass
     x = entry.get()#login
     y = entryy.get()#password
#how to include that data in array list "workerspass'?
     identif = int(identer.get())#checks if this id exists in the array.
```

Expected: I want entry from register to be stored in the dictionaries which is located in array. So basically I want to create basic registration system for entries.
Whole file available at: https://pastebin.com/Tij0dnb9

Comment: What have you tried, exactly? Adding a new element to a list is covered in any basic tutorial. But a list of mappings `{username: password}` does not seem like a useful representation.

Comment: Why not specify `workerspass` as a dict of dict ?

Comment: Read [Python Dictionary Quick Guide](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-dictionary-quick-guide) to see, you **don't** need a `list`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just wanted to make a simple data base for login and password

Comment: @stovfl got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
userspass = {
 'user1':'pass1',
 'user2':'pass2',
 'user3':'pass3'
 } #define dictionary like this

def validate_user(database,username,password):
    if (username, password) in database.items():
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

print(validate_user(userspass,'user1','pass1'))
print(validate_user(userspass,'user1','pass3'))
```

results:

```
1
0
```

I think this will suffice for your need. Let me know if you have any questions. :)

Comment: Thank you so much. So I can include new user now

Comment: I do have a question. How to create new entry in the list. I mean a function which will add 4th user.

Comment: Hi, great! So this is a question which can be asked from the security requirement point of view, for example, for a company environment you need to do this more securely, may be use a simple database connection. If you want to just do a personal project or so, you can even go with a config file or text file.

Comment: usually you want to have an interface UI for login for the user, how are u handling that now?

Comment: I do for personal purpose. UI is pretty much easy, the only problem is adding new users.

Comment: and you do not want to add manually in the userspass dictionary right?

Comment: How about making a txt/csv file from where you read the credentials?

Comment: >add manually in the userspass that is exactly I don't want it to do. I want it to be automatic

Comment: Making txt/csv is not bad idea. It is personal project, not a program for security.

Comment: Good luck then. I would also suggest to make a separate text file or csv, you can encrypt it later to make things secured from others, if required. and for adding new users you just need to do a text entry, not make a change in a program every time. Which is better practice. Cheers! :)